# Mongoose/MongoDB: Finding referenced documents within another referenced document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have a `Reservation` that has both a referenced `Traveler` and a `Property` associated with it, and a `Property` has an `Owner` associated with it, what is the best way to get all the `Reservation`s associated with an `Owner`?

I'm new with mongoose/mongodb, so I may be off in what my options are, but I wasn't sure if I should just add `owner` to the `ReservationSchema` similar to how I did with `traveler`. But then I also realized that `property` has an `owner` inside of that. So, would it be better to look through reservations, that has a property, that has an owner and try to return that? Is that even possible (performance wise and everything else considered)? And if it is, is that an appropriate time to use an index?

Or is there a way (with the schema design so far) that I can look up all the `property`s associated with an `Owner` and then see if those have a `Reservation` attached to it?

```
const ReservationSchema = new Schema({
  traveler: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: DOC_TYPE.USER,
    required: true,
  },
  property: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: DOC_TYPE.PROPERTY,
    required: true,
  }
   //all the other info
}

const PropertySchema = new Schema({
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: DOC_TYPE.USER,
  },
  //all the other info
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding owner to the reservation would make that query a bit simpler, but it would also make it much more complex to update the owner of a property.  Whether doing that is a good idea will depend on how often that information in needed, and how expensive it turns out to be to query it from the existing schema.

To find all reservations for properties with a specific owner, in a single query, without changing that schema you would need to use aggregation to:

- $match in the owner collection
- $lookup in the property collection for properties matching that owner
- $lookup in the reservations collection for reservations on those properties

Comment: Thank you, that helps get me in the right area. I appreciate it.